# Notification Hub metrics and best approach

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I have some questions about azure notificaiton hub. Actually i'm using notificaton hub only for sending direct push by rest api. I have created one notification hub for many push types. My questions:

1. How can i display metric per push type (tags), not by target platform.
2. What is the best approach when i have many push types, one notificaton for each push type or dedicated notification hub for push type.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i display metric per push type (tags), not by target platform

It seems that there is no such metric per push type(tags), we could get the supported metrics from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsofteventhubnamespaces).

> What is the best approach when i have many push types, one notificaton for each push type or dedicated notification hub for push type.

Based on my experience, we could use one notification for each push type. But if you want to get the metric of push type. It seems that is not supported.

We also need to pay more attention to the [notification limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#notification-hub-service-limits).

[image]